# return string value from SQL Server tables where column type is integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my mssql tables i have a clomun that data type is integer. and when i was try thats you know the return value is int.

```
select h.hekimlik_kod, h.hekim_adi, h.hekim_soyadi, h.il_kod, h.ilce_kod, h.islem_tarihi, h.durum
h.asm, il.aciklama as il_adi, ilce.aciklama as ilce_adi from hekim as h
left join il_ilce as il on il.ust_kod = 0 and il.kod = h.il_kod 
left join il_ilce as ilce on ilce.ust_kod = h.il_kod and ilce.kod = h.ilce_kod
```

int this sql statement "h.durum"' data type is integer. 
but i want to make thats.
when h.durum is 0 return string is Yönetici
when h.durum 1 string is Normal Kullanıcı

how can i do in sql?
thank you for patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question, but try replacing `h.durum` on your `SELECT` with the following:

```
CASE WHEN h.durum = 0 THEN 'Yönetici'
     WHEN h.durum = 1 THEN 'Normal Kullanıcı'
     ELSE '???' END AS some_column_alias
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select
  CASE
    WHEN h.durum = 0 THEN N'Yönetici'
    WHEN h.durum = 1 THEN N'Normal Kullanıcı'
  END CASE ColumnName,
  h.hekimlik_kod, h.hekim_adi, h.hekim_soyadi, h.il_kod, h.ilce_kod, h.islem_tarihi, h.durum
  h.asm, il.aciklama as il_adi, ilce.aciklama as ilce_adi
FROM hekim as h
  left join il_ilce as il on il.ust_kod = 0 and il.kod = h.il_kod 
  left join il_ilce as ilce on ilce.ust_kod = h.il_kod and ilce.kod = h.ilce_kod
;
```